Can't get rid of the "Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX"
I'm working on a multilingual document that uses the biblatex package to manage my bibliography. While the output looks correct, I'm getting a persistent error that I haven't been able to resolve despite trying various code tweaks (check this .log file).
Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

After digging a bit deeper, I discovered that the error only appears when I use a macro or environment that requires switching to a non-main language, as specified in the babel options. Specifically, I suspect that the issue is caused by the use of the otherlanguage environment with a non-main language as an option. Here's a minimal example that reproduces the warning:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=fr, main]{french}
\babelprovide[import=en]{english}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Donec varius orci eget risus.\cite{bertram}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{otherlanguage}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Could you kindly assist me in identifying the issue at hand? I would be grateful for any suggestions or comments you may have.

it looks as if biblatex doesn't realize that english has been loaded as you do it in \babelprovide and not as package option. Open an issue at the biblatex issue tracker.

@UlrikeFischer done, i've opened an issue
